# Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, listview, multiple-columns

I am new in Binding and WPF recently I've learned how to create a `listBox` with multiple columns using Binding tech

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="306,70,22,17" MouseDoubleClick="listBoxSS_MouseDoubleClick" Name="listBoxSS" >           
    <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="first_name " Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=First_name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="last_name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Last_name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="phone_number" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Phones[0]}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="notes" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Notes}" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and this is the code:

```
List<Student> arr = search.students();
        listBoxSS.ItemsSource = arr;
```

but the problem was when I tried to use add or remove item or clear

```
 listBoxSS.Items.Clear();
```

Please I need an example for using the items source or the way that I can ADD or Remove Item or Clear the list.

**EDIT:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="306,70,22,17" MouseDoubleClick="listBoxSS_MouseDoubleClick" Name="listBoxSS" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="first_name " Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=First_name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="last_name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Last_name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="phone_number" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Phones[0]}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="notes" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Notes}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and here is the code:

```
 ObservableCollection<Employee> Gemployees;
var employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(search.employees());
```

`search.employees()` get the list of all employees in my DB

```
 listBoxPE.ItemsSource = employees;
        Gemployees = employees;
```

now I can perform all the methods on Gemployees

```
 Gemployees.Remove((Student)listBoxSS.SelectedItem);
 Gemployees.Add((Student)listBoxSS.SelectedItem);
```

The `ListView` perform a refresh whenever I add or remove an Item from Gemployees!! Cool but still a little hard work on binding. Now I am doing an interface class to every ListView so I can put my stuff into it. It wont perform any flexibility in Adding Items.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're binding the `ItemsSource` to a property in the `DataContext` called `Items`, so to update the collection, you need to go to the `Items` property in the `DataContext` and clear it.

In addition, the `Items` property needs to be of type `ObservableCollection`, not `List` if you want it to update the UI whenever the underlying collection changes.

Your bit of code that sets the `ItemsSource` in the code behind is not needed and should be removed. You only need to set the `ItemsSource` in one place, not both.

Here's a simple example of how it can work:

```
// Using Students instead of Items for the PropertyName to clarify
public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

public MyConstructor()
{
    ...

    Students = search.students();
    listBoxSS.DataContext = this;
}
```

Now when you have:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" ... />
```

you're binding the `ItemsSource` to the `ObservableCollection<Student>`, and when you want to clear the list you can call:

```
Students.Clear()
```

Comment: thanks a lot it's work now with some changes I will Edit my question so you can see what I have done

Comment: I want to update the UI element when I remove an item from the list. The so-called TwoWay binding does not do it.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy Are you using an ObservableCollection<T>, which automatically raises change notifications for the UI to know it needs to update? A regular List<T> does not do this.

Comment: @Rachel, yes but obviously I'm missing something else that actually does the update - so I complain about it being called "TwoWay binding". It's a bit like claiming a car has electric windows but then nothing happens when you press the button.

Answer (score 19):

Weird but true:  the following errant keystrokes in my XAML file produced the error "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.":

```
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>x`
```

Note the `` x` ``  characters after the closing element tag.

Comment: Yeah, wierd but true: I had the following written: </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>> (note double closing bracket)

Comment: Thanks. Extra characters inside the tag was the culprit here.

Comment: Ha! In my case, I had written ">" instead of "/>", so an element was never closed. Now, why isn't this kind of thing detected at build time?

Comment: What's happening here is that any "loose text" between the <ItemsControl> and </ItemsControl> tags will be considered as data to be added to the ItemsCollection. I made exactly the same double-closing-bracket mistake as Maxim - in that I was telling it to bind to a datasource with ItemsSource, and ALSO accidentally put a single hardcoded item with the text ">" in.

Comment: @AlanSingfield Thanks for explaning the _reason_ behind the exception. Although it makes perfect sense, the exception sent me looking in other directions for quite a bit...

Answer (score 18):

I know this question has been answered about 2 years ago, however I had this problem myself as well and thought of a possible solution myself, which works. Maybe this doesn't work in certain scenarios and maybe I'm simply not seeing something, but it worked for me so I'm sharing it here:

```
listView.ClearValue(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
listView.ItemsSource = NewSource;
```

I sincerely hope this helps someone.

Comment: It Worked for me and was a much simpler approach.

Comment: This is analogous to removing the engine from a car to change gear and putting it back in again. However, given that WPF is so badly designed this it what I'm using to make it work. The alternative massive blocks of code to so a simple update are just not worth the effort.

Answer (score 13):

I think [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24212698/3195477) isn't quite clear.  Related to the rogue characters, this also causes the exception:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AnObservableCollection}">
    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

When what you meant was:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AnObservableCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Its easy to think the first is correct and the exception in no way explains what is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure that this really is the same root cause as the rogue character case. In this instance you are trying to add items in two ways - 1. through the ItemsSource binding, and 2. as a direct content addition (the label). Either is valid but not both simultaneously.

Comment: it raises the same exception and was a mistake I made when I was first learning wpf. I figured it'd be helpful to someone searching for that exception.  I don't really care what the root cause is.

Comment: I agree that your example was quite helpful.

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3):

You need to work against the collection that is data-bound to your `ItemsSource`. In order to get collection change notifications (when items get added or removed), you should use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx):

```
var students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(search.students());
listBoxSS.ItemsSource = students;

students.Clear();
students.Add(new Student("ABC"));
```

And you should remove the `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` declaration from your XAML.

Comment: This will not work because the `ItemsSource` is set, not bound. So changes to `students` will not be reflected in the `ListView`

Comment: @Rachel: Actually, no, changes to the `students` collection *do* update the `ListView`. The only difference that data-binding to a property would have made is that it could also raise notifications when another *collection* is assigned to the property (assuming the class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

Comment: You're right, it actually is updating correctly. That surprises me because I'm fairly sure I've encountered times when setting the value instead of binding it sets the property to a copy of the object, so updating the property doesn't update the UI. I still consider setting the value instead of binding it to be bad practice and would typically recommend against it though :)

Comment: In cases where you’re assigning *another* value to a property, then yes, the change would only get propagated to the UI the property is data-bound to. However, in cases where you’re changing something *within* the instance assigned to the property, then a simple assignment would suffice (assuming the instance internally implements change-notification mechanisms – such as, in this case, `INotifyCollectionChanged`).

Comment: I think I'm thinking of a `CollectionViewSource`, where you actually end up binding to `SomeCollection.DefaultView()`, and not actually `SomeCollection` :)

Comment: Ah, makes sense then. (And I usually prefer data-binding over assigning as well, just for the sake of keeping my declarations in XAML.)

Comment: @Douglas please see my Edit and tell me is what I am doing right?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message appear, resulting from a syntax error. It turns out I was accidentally defining an item in a `TreeView` that had an `ItemsSource` defined. I had defined a `DataTemplate` for the tree view, but accidentally put it directly in `<TreeView>` instead of `<TreeView.Resources>`, causing the error.

What I had:

```
<TreeView ItemSource ="{Binding Items}">
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate> ... </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate> ... </DataTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

What I should have had:

```
<TreeView ItemSource ="{Binding Items}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate> ... </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate> ... </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the ItemsSource property of the listbox to a public property inside the form's class.  Then try adding a removing from that, calling PropertyChanged inside the setter, instead of calling clear directly on the listbox items source.

Comment: could you pleas give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Always bind an ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection to avoid memory leaks. An ObservableCollection will also cause the display to update automatically with Add/Remove. I used to always bind to arrays before I learned this.

A useful source:
https://onewindowsdev.com/2016/09/22/a-memory-leak-may-occur-when-you-use-data-binding-in-windows-presentation-foundation/

1) For DataBinding in general the class you bind to should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. The exception to this is to use Mode=OneTime bindings.

2) An ItemsSource should always be a class that implements INotifyCollectionChange. The easiest way to do this is to use an ObservableCollection. ObservableCollection does have a constructor that takes in an IEnumerable which I've found useful.

3) If the ItemsControl is an ObservableCollection < SomeClass > than SomeClass should implement INotifyPropertyChange. You can then safely bind to individual properties of SomeClass.

Comment: please provide a summary of this link since it might be invalid one day

Comment: I've added some tips on DataBinding.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was totally unrelated issue. It was a silly syntax error where I forgot to wrap my `<style> </style>` with a `<DataGrid.Style> </DataGrid.Style>`.

Thanks Microsoft for the totally confusing error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and I eventually realized that I was trying to add a new item directly to the control's ItemsSource, rather than to the ObservableCollection that served as the ItemsSource.

I figured I'd post this, as it might help other novice wpfers.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I misunderstood the directions for a control and accidentally put it inside the datagrid control instead of outside.

```
    <DataGrid> 
        <mytag the tag for the open source control />
    </DataGrid>
```

Someone above mentioned extraneous characters, and all of the sudden I realized maybe DataGrid did not like it there.  I moved it and voila, the error

*Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.*

was gone!  It really had NOTHING to do with an ItemsSource, but it was confusing whatever parser is generating that Microsoft error.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another weird issue as what @Brett posted.
It seems that any wrong format or xaml contents you put inside a ComboBox, ListView (or other collection elements) would trigger this error.

For my case, I put my DataTemplate as a direct child of the ComboBox instead of inside a ComboBox.ItemTemplate:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding MyValidSource}>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!-- Notice I forgot to put the datatemplate inside ComboBox.ItemTemplate -->
        <!-- some templating code here -->
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Again, this only 'seems' to be the case as I haven't investigated further.

In anycase, my ItemsSource was valid but I was getting the same error for 'ItemSource in use'.
I think this is because the ItemSource is already assigned but since there are still items inside the ComboBox, it tried to add the items inside the collection.