# how to Remove item from one Listbox and add into another Listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am trying to remove selected item from one listbox and add that into new listbox as follows code

Binding on PageLoad:

Getting the records from database into a DataTable and bind that to Listbox.

```
lstBox1.DataContext = dtData;
```

Code Bind:

```
  List<object> _selecteditems = new List<object>();
  foreach (var item in lstBox1.SelectedItems)
  {
      _selecteditems.Add(item);
  }
  foreach (var item in _selecteditems)
  {
      lstBox1.Items.Remove(item);
      lstBox2.Items.Add(item);
  }
```

Design:

```
<ListBox Name="lstBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<ListBox Name="lstBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I am getting an error when removeing the item "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."

Comment: Well, exactly as said in the error message, you have to work with ItemsSource when your ListBoxes are binded. So modify your dtData for deleting and something else for inserting

Comment: Take a look at this Stackoverflow posting and see if it help also GOOGLE the Error Message and put WPF at the end you will get a lot of hits http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089104/operation-is-not-valid-while-itemssource-is-in-use-access-and-modify-elements-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried by following way and its working for me.

```
List<object> _selecteditems = new List<object>();
foreach (var item in lstBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    _selecteditems.Add(item);
}
foreach (var item in _selecteditems)
{
  DataRow dr = dtSelctedDest.NewRow();
  dr[0] = ((DataRowView)item).Row[0].ToString();
  dr[1] = ((DataRowView)item).Row[1].ToString();
  dtSelctedItem.Rows.Add(dr);
  dtAllItem.Rows.Remove(dtAllItem.Rows.Remove.Select(string.Format("ID='{0}'", ((DataRowView)item).Row[0].ToString()))[0]);
 }
 lstBox1.DataContext = dtAllItem;
 lstBox2.DataContext = dtSelctedItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't manipulate the items via the Items property, instead add/remove items from the List that the ListBox is bound to:

```
<ListBox Name="lstBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding myListProperty}">
  ...etc...
</ListBox>
```

If your `myListProperty` returns a collection that implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) (like the ObservableCollection does) then the listboxes will automatically show the new items as they are added and the removed items will instantly disappear.