# Keep ListBox with Database table synchronized

Tags: c#, wpf, database, listbox, itemssource

I have a **ListBox** (*listContacts*) that I fill it out of a **Table** (*Person*) from my DB (*DB1.mdf*) when my form loads for the first time:

```
class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

How I fill my listbox:

```
private void Initiation()
    {
        // Fill list:
        var DB = new Database();
        DataTable Persons = DB.TableFromDB(strMyDBFilePath, "SELECT * FROM Person", "Person");
        var listP = new List<Person>() { };
        foreach (DataRow dr in Persons.Rows)
            //listContacts.Items.Add(dr["Firstname"].ToString().Trim() + " " + dr["Lastname"].ToString().Trim());
            listP.Add(new Person()
            {
                Id = dr["Id"].ToString(),
                Firstname = dr["Firstname"].ToString().Trim(),
                Lastname = dr["Lastname"].ToString().Trim()
            });
        listContacts.ItemsSource = listP;
    }



class Database
{
    public DataTable TableFromDB(string DatabaseName, string Command, string TableName)
    {
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var cs = new SqlConnection(strSQLNetworkInterface + DatabaseName);
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(Command,cs);
        da.Fill(ds, TableName);
        return ds.Tables[TableName];
    }

    public void InsertToDB(Person Person, string TableName, string DatabaseName)
    {
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var cs = new SqlConnection(strSQLNetworkInterface + DatabaseName);
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + TableName, cs);

        da.Fill(ds, TableName);
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[TableName].NewRow();
        dr["Firstname"] = Person.Firstname;
        dr["Lastname"] = Person.Lastname;
        ds.Tables[TableName].Rows.Add(dr);
        var cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[TableName]);
    }
}
```

When I add a record to my **Table** (*Person*) using *InsertToDB*, it works fine. Next thing I need is to update my **ListBox** (*listContacts*). I couldn't just:

```
listContacts.Items.Add(pNew.Firstname + " " + pNew.Lastname);
```

It occurs this error:

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead

Now my question: **How to use ItemsSource to keep synchronized my ListBox?**

**Edit:**

Based on @Kirenenko's hint I've added this:

```
var listP = (List<Person>)(listContacts.ItemsSource);
listP.Add(pNew);
listContacts.ItemsSource = listP;
```

But it seems not updating my **ListBox**!

Comment: Add the item to `ListP`, not to `listContacts`

Comment: @Kirenenko Thank you. I've added some codes as above. But still not updating.

Comment: Check out MVVM pattern, bind your listContacts.ItemSource(in the view) to an ObservableCollection<Person> listP (in your view model).

Answer (score 0):

Based on question: [Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089104/operation-is-not-valid-while-itemssource-is-in-use-access-and-modify-elements-w) I've done this:

```
var listP = (List<Person>)(listContacts.ItemsSource);
listP.Add(pNew);
listContacts.ClearValue(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
listContacts.ItemsSource = listP;
```

And worked for me.
Thank you @Kirenenko and @Matthijs H!