# Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one dataGrid.

I want to delete one of the Rows form the dataGrid, by clicking the button from the UI (WPF).

The following was the code snippet to delete the row from the dataGrid, But I'm observing the Exception "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead".

Kindly help in fixing this.

```
   private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var selectedItem = dataGrid.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            dataGrid.Items.Remove(selectedItem);             
        }

    }
```

Comment: What are you assigning to `dataGrid.ItemsSource`? You need to modify the items source directly if you're using that as the source of the data.

Comment: @Alex Wiese, I'm assigning a DataTable to dataGrid.

Comment: In that case check my answer

Comment: you dont bind to overservable collection in WPF ? i think you must follow that practise if you are using WPF

Comment: check the answer that helps you to do it properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11089104/774575) (which interestingly was highly upvoted; other times).

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying data by assigning a `DataTable` to the `dataGrid.ItemsSource` property. This means you need to add/remove items by modifying that `DataTable` directly.

```
private DataTable _dataTable;

private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = dataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        _dataTable.Rows.Remove(selectedItem.Row); 
        _dataTable.AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: var selectedItem = ((DataRowView)dataGrid.SelectedItem)?.Row;
    "?.Row" is showing error as "Invalid expression".

Comment: @NagarajuKuricheti you might not be using the latest version of C#. I've updated the answer, try that