# Something error happens when I try to add an items to Data grid or clear the Data grid

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, code-behind

I have a data grid and it is empty at first. Then I need to add items when the user selects some data. But here it shows error like

Error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

I really didn't understand what is the problem here.

I have tried `datagridName.Items.clear();`  and `datagridName.Items.Add();`. but both did't work.

```
private void TextboxBarCodeTextchanged(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridSalesDetails.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < AllStockList.Count; i++)
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((sender as TextBox).Text))
      {
        if (AllStockList[i].BarCode.StartsWith((sender as TextBox).Text, 
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
          Stock vend = AllStockList[i] as Stock;
          DataGridSalesDetails.Items.Add(vend);
          DataGridSalesDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          DataGridSalesDetails.Items.Refresh();
          TotalReturnAmount = AllStockList.Sum(a => a.TotalAmount);
          HiddenTotalAount.Text = TotalReturnAmount.ToString();
          LabelFinalAmountValue.Content = TotalReturnAmount.ToString();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Expected Result is the Datagrid with added values. What I get is an error. Is there anyone to help me? I'm stuck with my project.

Comment: seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089104/operation-is-not-valid-while-itemssource-is-in-use-access-and-modify-elements-w

Answer (score 0):

When working with datagrids you should assign a collection of items to the itemSource of that datagrid. Instead of assigning the collection to the itemSource, you are trying to add a new item to that datagrid.

You'll need to filter the Stock objects you are interested in and add these to a collection.
When the iteration is completed and the Stock objects are added to the collection, you'll need to assign the collection to the ItemSource.

**Update from OP**

The itemssource of the datagrid is bound to an Observable collection.
And OP wants to save the old list of Stock Object Items.

```
ObservableCollection<Stock> StockItems = new ObserveableCollection<Stock>();

private void TextboxBarCodeTextchanged(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{

oldCollection = ObservableCollection;

for (int i = 0; i < AllStockList.Count; i++)
   {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((sender as TextBox).Text))
      {
          if (AllStockList[i].BarCode.StartsWith((sender as TextBox).Text, 
          StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
          {
             var stock = AllStockList[i] as Stock;

             StockItems.Add(stock);
           }
         }
      }
             DataGridSalesDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
             TotalReturnAmount = filteredCollection.Sum(a => a.TotalAmount);
             HiddenTotalAount.Text = TotalReturnAmount.ToString();
             LabelFinalAmountValue.Content = TotalReturnAmount.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I already have an `observable collection` which is my `Itemssource`.  `DataGridSalesDetails.ItemsSource = filteredCollection;` If I do like how do I get values from old `Itemssource`?

Comment: You should try adding the items to the observable, if any new values are detected the datagrid will perform an UI update containing the added items.

Comment: Ok. Let me try this

Comment: I added this to the observable collection. but observable collection and `stock` were different types. So I changed `stock` to the same type of observable collection. Now another error appears as,                                                  Cannot convert type  'BILLMATES.DbModels.Stock' to 'BILLMATES.DbModels.SalesReturnInvoiceData' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Comment: but at first, I need to do `DataGridSalesDetails.Items.Clear();` and this brings the same error

Comment: Create a new ObservableCollection of type Stock and set it to the DataGrids ItemsSource. You are interested in binding the Collection of Stock items, not the SalesReturnInvoiceData objects.