# Add new row to WPF Datagrid with binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, binding, datagrid

I am working on WPF datagrid, which I am using to show options to the user by combobox. My code looks something like this:

```
    <Grid>
    
        <DataGrid x:Name="DgvPerson" Height="Auto">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Person 1" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Person 2" />
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="USA" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="UK" />
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Button x:Name="BtnAddNewPerson" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Click="BtnAddNewPerson_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Add New Person..</Button>

</Grid>
```

And in behind Code:

```
Private Sub BtnAddNewPerson_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim newPerson As New Object
    DgvRobot.Items.Add(newPerson)
End Sub
```

Basically, what my code is saying, We have a datagrid of Person with Name(Combobox), Age(TextBox), Country(Combobox). And the user can click a button to add a new row with the same options.

Now let's say I want `Name` combobox to fill from DB. I have a `observablecollection` personName and which has Person202, Person505. And I make changes to code:

```
....
<DataGrid x:Name="DgvPerson" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding personName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
....
```

Now the code behind, If I keep the same then gives me error of:`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.'`

Now, How can I add a new row with binding so I can have the same options as the first row. I would prefer not to fill the personName from DB because it doesn't make sense to open that twice rather how can I copy/use the first row as itemsource for the second one? Is it possible? Or any other, easier way?
Answer with C# would also be okay as long as it will work on VB.

I really am stuck here. Little help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089104/operation-is-not-valid-while-itemssource-is-in-use-access-and-modify-elements-w)

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. Change your code to update the bound data source, not the control's `Items` collection directly. See proposed duplicate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer @PeterDuniho. The post is informative, but I am not sure how connect with my problem. In the proposed link, I can see they mentioned to have observablecollection of defined Class, as my class initialize with opening the DB which I don't want over and over. Where I want it to copy from last row.