# How to bind to a collection inside of a collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

I'm trying to bind an itemscontrol to a collection inside of another collection. To do this, I've layered an itemscontrol inside of another itemscontrol, like so:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MachinistUnreportedOps}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MultiJobOps}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="Op " />
                        <Run Text="{Binding JobOperation}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This will eventually be bound to a source from entity framework, but since I was having issues I just put this dummy data in my viewmodel:

```cs
MachinistUnreportedOps = new ObservableCollection<SimpleClass>()
{
    new()
    {
        MultiJobOps = new()
        {
            new() { JobOperation = 100 },
            new() { JobOperation = 101 },
            new() { JobOperation = 102 },
        },
    },
    new()
    {
        MultiJobOps = new()
        {
            new() { JobOperation = 103 },
            new() { JobOperation = 104 },
            new() { JobOperation = 105 },
        },
    },
};
```

(`SimpleClass` pretty much just holds some data, which I am trying to access in the above xaml. Obviously it has a `JobOperation` property, which is an int.)

Unfortunately, the same issue arises with this data and using EF:
`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.'`

with inner exception:
`System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.`

I've looked into this error, but most issues (like this one: [Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089104/operation-is-not-valid-while-itemssource-is-in-use-access-and-modify-elements-w)) seem to be about directly accessing the control and changing the items in it, which I'm not doing at all. I have no references to either itemscontrol in my code behind or viewmodel. I'm not even accessing the `MachinistUnreportedOps` collection in my code anywhere else, let alone modifying it. I figure I must be misunderstanding something about how `ItemsControl` works with its bound data. I'm still pretty new to WPF.

One thing I did find was an article I lost the link for, but it suggested defining an itemspanel as I did in the xaml above. No difference in behavior one way or the other. I don't much care what kind of panels are used, but grid would be nice for the inner itemscontrol as I hope to expand it.

Comment: The problem lies in your inner ItemsControl -- the one that binds to `MultiOpJobs`.  You have a DataTemplate in there but you forgot to put it inside of an `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put this in the form of an answer.  Your XAML should be like what is below.  The only change I made was to put your second `DataTemplate` inside an `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` tag.  Because that's why it's there;  You are using it to set the ItemTemplate property of the ItemsControl around it.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MachinistUnreportedOps}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MultiJobOps}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="Op " />
                            <Run Text="{Binding JobOperation}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm the only dev at my company right now so I don't have a second set of eyes to catch silly errors...

Comment: No worries.  Understanding what those exception messages are really trying to tell you in the mind of WPF is half the battle.